# How to use two or three button's logic in single button using CPP in QT

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt5, qtgui

I am beginner as the developer in QT, Here is the task for the button D, below is the code for the buttons A,B and C. Need to write code for the button D, if we press button D, it should execute the operations of A, B and C buttons ( one after one).

``````
 if(ui->radioButton_wake->isChecked()) // Button A
 {
     ui->label_lastCommand->setText("Last command: Wake");
     ui->progressBar->setMaximum(UPDATE_FREQUENCY * 122);
     pJMPX->RDS_Set_11A_Enable(true);
     progressTimer->start();
 }
 else if(ui->radioButton_beep->isChecked())  // Button B
 {
     ui->label_lastCommand->setText("Last command: Beep");
     ui->progressBar->setMaximum(UPDATE_FREQUENCY * (ui->doubleSpinBox_general->value() + 122));
     pJMPX->RDS_Set_11A_Enable(true);
     progressTimer->start();

     QTimer::singleShot(122000, this, [this](){
         pJMPX->RDS_Set_11A_data(0x0008, 0x0000);
     });
 }
 else if(ui->radioButton_beginPlayback->isChecked())  // Button c
 {
     ui->label_lastCommand->setText("Last command: Begin Playback");
     ui->progressBar->setMaximum(UPDATE_FREQUENCY * (ui->doubleSpinBox_general->value() + 122));
     pJMPX->RDS_Set_11A_Enable(true);
     progressTimer->start();

     QTimer::singleShot(122000, this, [this](){
         pJMPX->RDS_Set_11A_data(0x0005, 0x0000);
     });
 }
 else if(ui->radioButton->isChecked()) // Button D
 {
 // Code to execute operations of button A, B and C ( one after one ) ?
 }
 `````
``````

Comment: Why can't you just create 3 methods for each of the actions of A, B & C, & then call them as required, and call all of them when D is pressed?

Comment: I've seen a bunch of variants of this question today. You should all get together and gang up on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you got the code you are using, but it doesn't match the question you asked. I'm going to answer the question actually asked rather than try to fix the code. This is the way it is done in Qt.

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void aSlot();
    void bSlot();
    void cSlot();
    void dSlot();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

And the source

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(ui->pushButton,   &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::aSlot);
    connect(ui->pushButton_2, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::bSlot);
    connect(ui->pushButton_3, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::cSlot);
    connect(ui->pushButton_4, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::dSlot);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::aSlot()
{
    ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText("aSlot() called\n");
}

void MainWindow::bSlot()
{
    ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText("bSlot() called\n");
}

void MainWindow::cSlot()
{
    ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText("cSlot() called\n");
}

void MainWindow::dSlot()
{
    aSlot();
    bSlot();
    cSlot();
}
```

[image: screenshot of program running]

Comment: Thanks for the example. I have used same logic, but when i press it executing the buttons A, B and C operations all at a time. My requirement, it should complete the A and then come to B and then come to C. Eg: If buttons A, B and C are linked with 2 min song each, If I press button D, then it should play A, after completing A then it should play B and then C. Could you please help me in writing logic for this requirement.

Comment: You simply need a variable in the class to keep track of which button has already been pressed

Comment: Can you please provide sample code for the above example.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [QButtonGroup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html). This class can be registered with buttons and later have a single function `buttonClicked` be called when one is clicked. A version of this function takes an identifier you specified when adding the buttons, another takes the button object itself. It makes it easy to have many buttons be handled by a single class through slots.